# Linked List Destructor executes with Valgrind but not on its own

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind

I have the following struct:

```
class List{
public: //Functions go here
    typedef struct node{
    string data;
    node* prev;
    node* next;
}* nodePtr;

nodePtr head;
nodePtr curr;
nodePtr temp;
nodePtr tail;

List();
//~List();
    void addToEnd(string addData);
    void addToBeg(string addData);
    void DeleteList();
    //More functions not included//
};
```

with constructor:

```
List::List(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}
```

and to delete nodes:

```
void List::DeleteList(){
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        temp = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        curr = temp;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code takes in numbers and performs addition and multiplication on them by partitioning the numbers into nodes. I call DeleteList() at the end of each function for each List. When I run the code with Valgrind, my output completes with the correct answers even though it says "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" on a few of the function calls.

When I execute the program along using gcc, I get a "pointer being freed was not allocated". What is the difference between the two execution methods? And why is gcc saying that the pointer wasn't allocated?

Adding a node looks like:

```
void List::addToEnd(string addData){ //adds to end of linked list
    //nodePtr n = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node));
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
        n->prev = curr;
        tail = n;
    }
    else{
        n->prev = NULL;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}
```

edit: Complete code for reference:

```
//structure for assembling doubly linked list.
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

class List{
public: //Functions go here
    typedef struct node{
        string data;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;
    nodePtr tail;

    List();
    ~List();
    void addToEnd(string addData);
    void addToBeg(string addData);
    List::nodePtr returnHead();
    List::nodePtr returnNext(List::nodePtr n);
    List::nodePtr returnPrev(List::nodePtr n);
    List::nodePtr returnTail();
    void DeleteList();
    void PrintList();
    void ConvertHead();
    void DeleteNode(string delData);
    string ListValue();
    string returnValue(List::nodePtr n);
};
//Functions
List addLists(List a, List b, long long nodeLength);
List multLists(List a, List b, long long nodeLength);
string doArithmetic(string num1, string num2, string op, long long nodSiz);
string removeSpaces(string input);


int main(int argc, char** argv){

  string sentence, sent2, operation, arg1, arg2;
  long long digitCount;
  int op;

  //Takes in the first argument and finds the first double quote
  //Uses what is in the quotes as the filename
  string str (argv[1]);

  size_t firstEqual = 6;

  size_t semicolon = str.find_first_of(";");

  size_t secondEqual = semicolon + 17;

  std::string file = str.substr(firstEqual, semicolon - firstEqual);
  digitCount = stoll(str.substr(secondEqual, str.length()));

  //Opens the file designated in the argument  
  ifstream inputFile (file.c_str());

  while(getline(inputFile, sentence)){
    sent2 = removeSpaces(sentence);
    op = sent2.find_first_of("+*");
    arg1 = sent2.substr(0,op);
    arg2 = sent2.substr(op+1,string::npos);
    //cout << "arg1: " << arg1 << " arg2: " << arg2 << " Operation: " << sent2.substr(op,1) << endl;
    cout << sent2 << "=";
    cout << doArithmetic(arg1, arg2, sent2.substr(op,1), digitCount) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


string doArithmetic(string num1, string num2, string op, long long nodSiz){

    long long nodeSize = nodSiz;
    string numberOne = num1; //14
    string numberTwo = num2;
    string answer;

    List value1, value2, result;

    //cout << numberOne << endl;
    //assigns values as strings to value1
    if(strlen(numberOne.c_str())%nodeSize != 0){
        value1.addToEnd(numberOne.substr(0,strlen(numberOne.c_str())%nodeSize));

        for(int i=0; i < strlen(numberOne.c_str())/nodeSize; i++){
            value1.addToEnd(numberOne.substr(strlen(numberOne.c_str())%nodeSize + i*nodeSize,nodeSize));
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0; i < strlen(numberOne.c_str())/nodeSize; i++){
            value1.addToEnd(numberOne.substr(strlen(numberOne.c_str())%nodeSize + i*nodeSize,nodeSize));
        }
    }
    //value1.PrintList();

    //cout <<numberTwo<<endl;
    //assigns values as strings to value2
    if(strlen(numberTwo.c_str())%nodeSize != 0){
        value2.addToEnd(numberTwo.substr(0,strlen(numberTwo.c_str())%nodeSize));

        for(int i=0; i < strlen(numberTwo.c_str())/nodeSize; i++){
            value2.addToEnd(numberTwo.substr(strlen(numberTwo.c_str())%nodeSize + i*nodeSize,nodeSize));
        }
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0; i < strlen(numberTwo.c_str())/nodeSize; i++){
            value2.addToEnd(numberTwo.substr(strlen(numberTwo.c_str())%nodeSize + i*nodeSize,nodeSize));
        }
    }
    //value2.PrintList();

    if(op == "+"){ 
        result = addLists(value1, value2, nodeSize);
    }
    else{
        result = multLists(value1, value2, nodeSize);
    }

    result.ConvertHead();
    answer = result.ListValue();

    value1.DeleteList();
    value2.DeleteList();
    result.DeleteList();
    return answer;
}

List multLists(List a, List b, long long nodeLength){
    List n;
    List::nodePtr aPoint, bPoint;
    long long valueA, valueB, product;
    long long leftover = 0;
    string filler;
    long long lengthDiff;
    int counterA = 0;
    int counterB = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < nodeLength;i++) filler = "0" + filler;

    bPoint = b.returnTail();
    while(bPoint != NULL){
        //cout << "B Point" << endl;
        valueB = stoll(b.returnValue(bPoint));
        leftover = 0;
        aPoint = a.returnTail();
        counterA = 0;
        while(aPoint != NULL){
            //cout << "A Point" << endl;
            List temp;
            valueA = stoll(a.returnValue(aPoint));
            product = valueA * valueB + leftover;

            lengthDiff = to_string(product).length() - nodeLength;

            if(to_string(product).length() > nodeLength){
                temp.addToBeg(to_string(product).substr(to_string(product).length()-nodeLength,nodeLength));
                leftover = stoll(to_string(product).substr(0,lengthDiff));
            }
            else{
                temp.addToBeg(to_string(product));
                leftover = 0;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < counterA + counterB; i++){
                temp.addToEnd(filler);
            }
            n = addLists(n,temp,nodeLength);
            temp.DeleteList();  
            aPoint = a.returnPrev(aPoint);
            counterA = counterA + 1;
        }
        bPoint = b.returnPrev(bPoint);
        counterB = counterB + 1;
    }
    if(leftover != 0) n.addToBeg(to_string(leftover));

    return n;
}



List addLists(List a, List b, long long nodeLength){
    List n;
    List::nodePtr aPoint, bPoint;
    long long valueA, valueB, sum;
    long long leftover = 0;
    long long lengthDiff;
    string input;

    aPoint = a.returnTail();
    bPoint = b.returnTail();

    while(aPoint != NULL || bPoint != NULL){
        if(aPoint != NULL) valueA = stoll(a.returnValue(aPoint));
        else valueA = 0;

        if(bPoint != NULL) valueB = stoll(b.returnValue(bPoint));
        else valueB = 0;

        sum = valueA + valueB + leftover;
        if(to_string(sum).length() > nodeLength){ 
            input = to_string(sum).substr(to_string(sum).length()-nodeLength,nodeLength);
        }
        else {
            input = to_string(sum);
        }

        lengthDiff = nodeLength-to_string(sum).length();

        if(nodeLength > to_string(sum).length()){
            for(int i=0; i < nodeLength-to_string(sum).length();i++){
                // cout << "sumLength: " << to_string(sum).length() << endl;
                input = "0" + input;
            }
        }
        n.addToBeg(input);

        if(to_string(sum).length() > nodeLength){
            leftover = stoll(to_string(sum).substr(0,to_string(sum).length() - nodeLength));
        }
        else leftover = 0;

        if(aPoint != NULL) aPoint = a.returnPrev(aPoint);
        if(bPoint != NULL) bPoint = b.returnPrev(bPoint);
        // cout << "sum: " << sum << " sum.length(): " << to_string(sum).length() << " leftover: " << leftover << endl;
        // cout << "lengthDiff: " << to_string(sum).substr(0,to_string(sum).length() - nodeLength) << endl;
    }

    if(leftover != 0) n.addToBeg(to_string(leftover));

    return n;
}

List::List(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

List::~List(){
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        temp = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        //free(curr);
        curr = temp;
    }
    head = curr = temp = tail = NULL;
}

void List::addToEnd(string addData){ //adds to end of linked list
    //nodePtr n = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node));
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n;
        n->prev = curr;
        tail = n;
    }
    else{
        n->prev = NULL;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}

void List::addToBeg(string addData){ //adds to beginning of linked list
    //nodePtr n = (nodePtr)malloc(sizeof(node));
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->prev = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL){
        curr = head;
        while(curr->prev!= NULL){
            curr = curr->prev;
        }
        curr->prev = n;
        n->next = curr;
        head = n;
    }
    else{
        n->prev = NULL;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}

List::nodePtr List::returnHead(){
    return head;
}

List::nodePtr List::returnNext(List::nodePtr n){
    return n->next;
}

List::nodePtr List::returnPrev(List::nodePtr n){
    return n->prev;
}

List::nodePtr List::returnTail(){
    return tail;
}

string List::returnValue(List::nodePtr n){
    return n->data;
}

void List::DeleteList(){
    temp = head;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        temp = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        //free(curr);
        curr = temp;
    }
    head = curr = tail = temp = NULL;
}

void List::ConvertHead(){
    long long convert;
    curr = head;
    convert = stoll(curr->data);
    curr->data = to_string(convert); 
}


void List::PrintList(){
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

string List::ListValue(){
    string value;
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL){
        value = value + curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return value;
}

string removeSpaces(string input){ //found on cplusplus.com
  int length = input.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     if(input[i] == ' ') input.erase(i, 1);
  }
  return input;
}
```

Example command line prompt:

```
./a.out "input=test0.txt; digitsPerNode =3"
```

with example input file named test0.txt:

```
0*0
0+1
2*3
2*2000000000000000
2*3
1+10
10000000000000000+1
12345667890123456789 + 8765432109876543210
999999999999999999999 + 1
```

Comment: Post a complete but minimal example that readers can try.

Comment: What destructor are you referring to? I don't see any destructors in this code.

Comment: Destructor is commented out in the code.

Comment: Do you reuse the same `List` object after calling `DeleteList()`? It leaves the object in inconsistent state. No other function can be called after for that object. To reuse the obeject `DeleteList()` must reset all pointers `head = curr = tail = temp = NULL`.

Comment: When you "execute the program along using gcc"? You *build the executable* using gcc, you then run the executable by itself. Is gcc really telling you that an unallocated pointer is being freed? That sounds like a run-time error, so either 1) something else is telling you that, 2) gcc is telling you something else, or 3) gcc is smarter than I thought it was. Please give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can stop guessing.

Comment: @robert and SergeyA I tried using List::~List but I was getting the same run time error, so I tried to explicitly delete the nodes using List::DeleteList().

Orest I also tried head=curr=tail=temp=NULL; but I'm still getting "pointer being freed was not allocated".

Beta You are correct! It is a run time error, not a compile time error.

Comment: That's a lot of code. What have you changed, since it was last working?

Comment: @Beta I implemented the code with single inputs at a time and it worked. Since, I've added in the main function that reads in the file, values, and operations. I don't think I can minimize the code anymore without maintaining full functionality.

Comment: You don't have to maintain full functionality; all you have to maintain is the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy constructor and assignment operator are required for such class, since it holds pointers.
The default copy constructor only makes a copy of class members.

So, if a local class instance is returned from a function the result contains pointers to invalid nodes that are deleted during destruction of the local object:

```
List multLists(List a, List b, long long nodeLength)
{
    List n;
    //... construct nodes of n      
    return n;
}

// result holds only body of returned n; nodes are already deleted
result = multLists(value1, value2, nodeSize);
```

Copy constructor and assignment operator with deep object copy resolve that issue:

```
// copy constructor
List::List(const List& l) :
    head(nullptr), curr(nullptr), temp(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
{
    for (nodePtr i = l.head; i; i = i->next)
        addToEnd(i->data);
}

// C++11 move constructor
List::List(List&& l) :
    head(l.head), curr(l.curr), temp(l.temp), tail(l.tail)
{
    // keep original object in consistent state
    l.head = nullptr;
    l.curr = nullptr;
    l.temp = nullptr;
    l.tail = nullptr;
}

// assignment operator
List& List::operator=(const List& l)
{
    if (this == &l)
        return *this;

    // for exception safety at first copy to temporary
    List tmp(l);

    // move temporary to this
    *this = move(tmp);

    return *this;
}

// C++11 move assignment operator
List& List::operator=(List&& l)
{
    if (this == &l)
        return *this;

    // free current list
    DeleteList();
    // move to this
    head = l.head;
    curr = l.curr;
    temp = l.temp;
    tail = l.tail;
    // keep original object in consistent state
    l.head = nullptr;
    l.curr = nullptr;
    l.temp = nullptr;
    l.tail = nullptr;

    return *this;
}
```

The adding to begin also should be fixed:

```
void List::addToBeg(string addData){ //adds to beginning of linked list
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->prev = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL){
        n->next = head;
        head->prev = n;
        head = n;
    }
    else{
        n->next = NULL;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}
```

---

*Other remarks*

Since the project compilation requires C++11 there is `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

It looks that `addToEnd()` may be optimized. The `while` loop is not needed to find the last list item, since there is `tail` pointer.

It makes sense to avoid deep object copies during function calls. It is better to pass constant references:

```
List multLists(const List& a, const List& b, long long nodeLength)
```

Of course here the code should be adjusted to proper usage of `const` qualifiers.

Comment: The while loop in `addToBeg` can also be removed, by using the `head` pointer.